# Cannot initialize zend_mm storage [win32]

Tags: php, apache, multiprocessing

The stress test I am running makes many connections to my Apache 2.2 running on Windows server 2008 r2 64-bit concurrently. After ~500 (-/+10) connections made I get this error in error.log Apache:

> Cannot initialize zend_mm storage [win32]

I have tried increasing the `memory_limit` in `php.init` but did not help. Why after increasing the memory_limit it still fails on the same number of connections?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you have exhausted your memory pool. Stress testing can do this. Even if you raise the PHP limits, you only have so much memory to allocate on your server. You said your server is 32 bit, meaning you have a maximum of 4GB of RAM plus your swap file. 500 connections could easily overwhelm a server that small.

Comment: I'm sorry false information (question edited), the server is 64-bit windows 2008 r2 with 4 GB RAM. But your statement would still be true. But how much memory is being allocated per connection? is it configurable in PHP?

Comment: Each PHP thread gets its own memory pool (you'll get a very different error when PHP overruns that constraint) and then Apache gets some memory as well. But you're hitting the hard memory cap, not one of the soft caps. Even if you tweak it some, I'm not sure you'll be able to make a server with that little in resources do 500 concurrent connections. Consider a VM with more processors/memory

Comment: Also consider that, even if you did make it live with that small of a RAM pool, it's going to be paging to disk like crazy to keep up.

Comment: It would need to run maximum 3000 concurrent connections. Does it mean I need a around 16GB of RAM on my server? 

I just need to know the exact amount of memory that is getting allocated for PHP to be able to know how much RAM at the end I need to cover all 3000 connections.

Comment: I can't tell you how much you need. Are you running your database on the same server? What kind of overhead does your application have? Total throughput will depend on more variables than we can discuss here. But I would experiment with different VMs and see if you can find your sweet spot.

Comment: It doesn't get to a point of using DB. Also I don't see the RAM allocation going more than available, in fact it increases about 100MB for 400 successful connections. This makes me think the RAM may not be the issue and PHP is not that much memory thirsty that we are talking about (~4GB).

Comment: Well, go into `php.ini` and raise the cap on each thread and see if that helps. At this point, you'll have to do trial and error

Comment: What flags/directive except memory_limit would worth changing?

Comment: If I were you I'd ask that over at http://serverfault.com/. You're more likely to have someone who could help you optimize your web server and PHP

Comment: It wasn't anything to do with Apache 32-bit or 64-bit. I will add my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So finally found out that if was the number of `ThreadsPerChild` in `httpd-mpm.conf` which was:

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild      1500
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
</IfModule>
```

I have changed it to:

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild      64
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
</IfModule>
```

And it is working fine.